# How to fix Froala editor tooltip incorrect position when its hover

Tags: javascript, typescript, froala

Anyone can help me how to fix this issue in froala editor. I'm using froala toolbar inside a modal, when I hover the tooltip position is incorrect its show outside the modal.I'm using froala editor in the other components and the tooltip position is okay.  this only component have a issue in tooltip [enter image description here][1]

this is its look like
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfCvA.png

Javascript:

```
    froala_options: FroalaOptions = {
    fullPage: true,
    key: FROALA_LICENSE_KEY,
    attribution: false,
    imageUploadURL: '',
    imageAllowedTypes: FROALA_EDITOR_ALLOWED_IMAGE_TYPES,
    toolbarButtons: WEB_TOOLBAR_BUTTONS,
    pluginsEnabled: PLUGINS_ENABLED_WEB,
    placeholderText: 'Enter your review request template here',
    emoticonsUseImage: false,
    pastePlain: true,
    zIndex: 1000,
    events: {
      'contentChanged': function() {
        let text = this.html.get() || '';

        text = text ? text.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'").replace(/[\u201C\u201D]/g, '"') : '';

        localStorage.setItem('message_rich_text', text);
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML :

```
<div [formGroup]="reviewRequestContentForm" class="w-full mb-1">
    <textarea 
           formControlName="reviewRequestContent" 
           [froalaEditor]="froala_options"
           client-name-key>
    </textarea>
</div>
```